# Default Browser for certain application

Tags: browser, default-programs, default-browser

I use google chrome browser for private stuff, but on the same machine I have my work toolset. For work things I use Firefox, and I would be really happy If I could assign it as default for HipChat (my work communicator app).

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem and here is what I've done in order to open links from the Slack application in Firefox browser while Google Chrome is my default browser.

First you have to create a bash script that will recognize environment variable. I used `DEFAULT_BROWSER` variable and the script is in the `/home/max/.scripts/default-browser.sh` file, which is displayed below :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$DEFAULT_BROWSER" == "" ]
then
  DEFAULT_BROWSER=google-chrome
fi

$DEFAULT_BROWSER "$@"
```

Then you have to create a desktop application (/usr/share/applications/default-browser.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Default Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Access the Internet
Exec=/home/max/.scripts/default-browser.sh %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
```

Now you can set this new desktop app as a default browser:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser default-browser.desktop
```

After doing all these steps you should be able to set the default browser via the environment variable. Try do the following:

```
DEFAULT_BROWSER=firefox slack
```

All links you open from `slack` should be opened in Firefox.

However, if you don't want to set this variable every time and run Slack from the terminal you can modify `/usr/share/applications/slack.desktop` as seen below :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Slack
StartupWMClass=Slack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=env DEFAULT_BROWSER=firefox /usr/bin/slack %U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/slack;
```

The main line is:

```
Exec=env DEFAULT_BROWSER=firefox /usr/bin/slack %U
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this great explanation! :+1

Comment: You can use ~/.local/share/applications to limit the change to your user

Answer (score 2):

you can make a launcher to open it in firefox.

Open your favorite text editor. type the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=HipChat
Comment=Work Chat
GenericName=HipChat
X-GNOME-FullName=HipChat
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr www.hipchat.com/sign_in
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox-esr
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupWMClass=Firefox-esr
StartupNotify=true
```

Save the file as `HipChat.desktop`. From the file manager, right click on the file and set as executable.You should now have a working launcher that opens HipChat in Firefox. To have it appear in your menu, open a terminal navigate to where your file is and type:

```
sudo cp hipchat.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

NOTE: if you are not using ESR, or if it is located in a different folder on your system, edit the references to firefox as is needed.

Comment: That is not what i meant, I have dekstop app HipChat, and when somebody sends a link to a webpage in this app, I want to have Firefox opened instead of Chrome, when I click the link.

Comment: check the settings for Hip Chat, if it doesn't have a browser selection, then you'd have to set the system default to firefox. Note about using the web based app: firefox will open links in firefox.