# Using different browsers to open links in different apps

Tags: bash, firefox, google-chrome, snap, default-browser

I'm using one app (firefox) for personal things and want to have that as my default browser. For my work, I use google chrome and I want the links from my work chat (rocket.chat) to open in chrome. I tried the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000716/default-browser-for-certain-application) from @maxim but it doesn't seem to work. I have the following script saved in ~/.scripts/default-browser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$DEFAULT_BROWSER" == "" ]
then
  DEFAULT_BROWSER=firefox
fi
$DEFAULT_BROWSER "$@"
```

and added a file default-browser.desktop to /usr/share/applications/

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Default Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Access the Internet
Exec=/home/micha/.scripts/default-browser.sh %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=firefox
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
```

This default-browser.desktop is set as my default browser. This works with, for example, sublime. Running

```
DEFAULT_BROWSER=google-chrome subl
```

and opening a link in sublime opens it in google chrome, but

```
DEFAULT_BROWSER=google-chrome rocketchat-desktop
```

doesn't work. For some reason, it won't set the environment variable. Is there another way to have different default browsers per app or some way to pass an environment variable to rocket chat? Does it have to do with the fact that rocket chat is a snap app?