# Each default browser for different workspaces

Tags: workspaces

I use google chrome browser for private stuff, but on the same machine I have my work apps. I've created two workspaces and use one for work and second for private stuff. For work things I use Firefox, and I would be really happy If I could assign it as default browser for work workspace and Google chrome for another workspace.
I red this thread [Default Browser for certain application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000716/default-browser-for-certain-application) and seems it can be applied for my case, just a question how I can recognize current workspace from script?
Or there is another solution nowdays?
My Ubuntu is 22.04.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple desktops?  My system has Ubuntu Desktop (thus GNOME), Xubuntu Desktop (thus Xfce), Lubuntu Desktop (thus LXQt)... installed, ie. I use a multi-desktop system, but is that what you meant? You want one desktop browser when using a LXQt Desktop session, another when using GNOME Desktop session, etc.   I suspect you meant *workspace* and not *desktop* (see https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces.html.en)

Comment: Thank you for a note ondeed, I've mentioned the workspaces, fixed it in my question